# Second derivative of parametric equation at given point.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, parametric, gre-exam

Let $f(t)=(t^2+2t,3t^4+4t^3), t>0$. Find the value of the second derivative, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$at the point $(8,80)$

This is a past Math subject GRE question, and the usual formula: for second parametric derivatives $$\frac{\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}}{(\frac{dx}{dt})^3}$$ took me much longer than 2.5 minutes (the average time per question) to compute. I'm thinking there has to be a faster way than actually computing all those partials, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Which "usual formula" in particular? I'm no Math GRE expert, but I'd imagine solving for t, writing the second component (y) in terms of the first (x) for general t, and twice-differentiating. Just guttural instinct

Comment: @QuantumFool I love the malapropism! "Guttural instinct." I'm using that one in the future.

Comment: @QuantumFool I can't express either either x or y as a function of t in this case. I'm editing the question to insert the "usual formula"!

Comment: Can you comment on how much longer? Also were certain bits which took much longer than others?

Comment: I'm not US based so my understanding is GRE is for after doing an undergraduate degree. Does the GRE Math exam assume that the degree was a Mathematics one?

Comment: @IanMiller I assume most every student taking the Math subject GRE test is finishing an undergrad degree in Math. Rarely physicists will take it to bolster their applications.

I haven't timed my calculations, the man below gave the answer, I was just being sloppy. There's no real issue here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1 - Derivatives**

**Speed:** Derivatives of polynomials in expanded form should be basically automatic for anyone doing/done an calculus course so the speed is basically as quickly as you write.

$\frac{dy}{dt}=12t^3+12t^2$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=36t^2+24t$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=2t+2$ and $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=2$

**Step 2: Find $t$**

**Speed:** There is some work involved in finding $t$. However it only involves solving a quadratic so should be quick. The quadratic is not difficult so again basically as quickly as you can write it down.

Solving: $t^2+2t=8$ $\rightarrow$ $t^2+2t-8=0$ $\rightarrow$ $(t-2)(t+4)=0$ $\rightarrow$ $t=2$ as $t>0$.

**Step 3 - Evaluate Expression** (Edited slightly for no calculator comment)

**Speed:** Do not try and simply the algebraic expression for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. Just substitute in $t=2$. This is just arithmetic so should be pretty quick.

$$\left(\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)_{t=2}=\left(\dfrac{\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\frac{dy}{dt}}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^3}\right)_{t=2}=\dfrac{(36\cdot2^2+24\cdot2)\cdot(2\cdot2+2)-2\cdot(12\cdot2^3+12\cdot2^2)}{(2\cdot2+2)^3}$$

To calculator this efficiently in your head/paper use arithmetic factorizing to avoid having to deal with big numbers. Below is the steps I would be doing in my head/book (I certainly wouldn't be writing them all down).

$$=12\cdot\left(\frac{(3\cdot2^2+2\cdot2)\cdot6-2\cdot(2^3+2^2)}{6^3}\right)$$

$$=12\cdot2\cdot\left(\frac{(3\cdot2+2)\cdot6-(2^3+2^2)}{6^3}\right)$$

$$=12\cdot2\cdot\left(\frac{8\cdot6-12}{6^3}\right)$$

$$=12\cdot2\cdot6\cdot\left(\frac{8-2}{6^3}\right)$$

$$=\frac{6\cdot2\cdot2\cdot6\cdot6}{6^3}$$

$$=4$$

**Personal Reflection**

Having a BSc and interest in Mathematics I would expect myself to take about and 60 seconds for this question using the formula you provided. If I was to use @QuantumFool's guttural instinct technique it would be more like 3 minutes as the calculus/algebra becomes more involved.

Obviously different people will have different experiences.

Comment: Unfortunately, no calculators allowed. :-| 

Your substituting for 2 right away made everything a lot easier, I had many more multiplications to do. I'm guessing we've brought this down to where if you know the steps you can complete them within ~150 seconds. Thanks for the detailed response. I think you deserve the answer.

Comment: Without a calculator then it would be important to know some mental arithmetic 'tricks'. I've updated my answer to include examples.

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to say now than during an examination !

I suppose that the idea was to work the numerator

$$x=t^2+2 t\qquad , \qquad x'=2 t+2\qquad , \qquad x''=2$$
$$y=3 t^4+4 t^3\qquad , \qquad y'=12 t^3+12 t^2\qquad , \qquad y''=36 t^2+24 t$$
$$x' y''-y'x''=(2 t+2) \left(36 t^2+24 t\right)-2 \left(12 t^3+12 t^2\right)=48 t^3+96 t^2+48 t$$ $$x' y''-y'x''=48 t (t+1)^2$$ $$\frac{x' y''-y'x''}{(x')^3}=\frac{48 t (t+1)^2}{8(t+1)^ 3}=\frac{6 t}{t+1}$$

Now, since $t>0$, $$x=t^2+2t=8 \implies t^2+2t+1=9\implies (t+1)^2=9\implies t=2$$ we can just check that $t=2\implies y=80$. So, we have the point and the derivative is immediate.

Trying to immediately express $y$ as a function of $x$ is not much simpler $$x=t^2+2 t\implies x+1=(t+1)^2\implies t=\sqrt{x+1}-1\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was being sloppy under time pressure and didn't factor the numerator. In retrospect perhaps I should delete this, the real answer is: be quick but don't hurry!

Comment: @Craig. Two points : first, as I said, I did not have the pressure of being in an exam. Second : when you face problems which look complex and you have a short time to solve thems, there must be a "simple" trick. Good luck.

Comment: @craig One other point in regards to speed. You don't need to do the algebraic simplification shown here. You can substitute in $t=2$ then simplify. You will then be doing arithmetic rather than algebraic simplification and hopefully less likely to make a mistake.

Comment: @IanMiller. For sure, indeed !! I am just feeling stupid now. Cheers.

Comment: Nah. Your steps are good for showing how its done. I was mainly addressing the time concern the OP mentioned as developing time pressure strategies is important to master for exam situations.

Answer (score 1):

How I would think about this problem:

We want $(t^2+2t,3t^4+4t^3) = (8,80)$, so $t^2+2t = 8\implies (t+1)^2 = 9 \implies t+1 = \pm 3 \implies t = -1\pm 3 = 2$ or $-4$. So $t=2$.

Now $x=t^2+2t\implies \frac{dx}{dt} = 2t+2$ and $y = 3t^4+4t^3\implies\frac{dy}{dt} = 12t^3+12t^2$, so
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{12t^3+12t^2}{2t+2} = \frac{6t^2(2t+2)}{2t+2} = 6t^2.$$
Well that simplifies things a lot! We want $\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}$, and
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)/\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = \left(\frac{d}{dt}(6t^2)\right)/(2t+2) = \frac{12t}{2t+2} = \frac{6t}{t+1}.$$
With $t=2$, this becomes $\frac{6(2)}{2+1} = \frac{6*2}{3} = \boxed{4}$.

---

Comments: I don't like cumbersome formulas, so when asked to find $\frac{dy^2}{dx^2}$, my "instinct" would say to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ first, and then take its derivative. I actually ran into this problem while practicing for the GRE, and when I first did it I made the mistake of taking the result $\frac{dy}{dx} = 6t^2$ and differentiating in $t$ to get the answer, essentially evaluating $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$ instead of $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$. So in my biased view the trickiest part of the problem was to not make that mistake, since otherwise the problem seemed designed to make calculations not terrible (given that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ ended up being a nice, short expression).